# Can raster maps be stored in a SQL Server spatial database?

Tags: raster, sql-server

Can raster maps be stored in a SQL Server spatial database?

And if so, how?

*... I'm aware of VARBINARY and FILESTREAM for images, but can only see GEOMETRIC and GEOGRAPHY for vector data*

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this ability, but I think it's only for ArcSDE:

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/install-st-raster-sqlserver.htm

Answer (score 0):

Not for analysis, but our BI team uses BLOB format to store raster pictures for maps.

Comment: But are these just pictures, rather than properly georeferenced rasters?

Comment: that's right....

Answer (score 0):

[PostGIS](https://postgis.net) databases handles rasters. I have never tried it myself but you could read more about it [in their FAQ](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_FAQ.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my question was about SQL Server, not PostGIS  :-(